# Suppose $A \subset \mathbb{R}$ is bounded, not compact. Continuous but not uniformly continuous

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

Suppose that a set $A \subseteq \mathbb{R}$ is bounded and not compact. Show that there is a function which is continuous on $A$, but not uniformly continuous.

I can see that this is the converse of a corollary to Heine-Borel and where this fails is being able to generate a finite subcover related to our $\delta$. I don't totally understand that proof so I don't quite see how that relates and so I am unsure of where to start this. Thanks for the help!

Here is what I have gotten through thus far

Assume we have a set $A$ that is bounded but not compact. From this we observe that $A$ is not closed. Now, let $f$ be defined on all of $\mathbb{R}$ and be continuous on $A$, then we have if $|x-x_0|<\delta_0$ then $\|f(x)-f(x_0)|<\varepsilon$. Since $A$ is not closed we know there is an accumulation point of $A$, say $a_0$, such that $a_0 \notin A$.\
                If $f$ were to be uniformly continuous then there would exist a $\delta$ such that if $|x-y|<\delta$, then $|f(x)-f(y)|<\varepsilon$. We consider $|x-a_0|<\delta$. Then $|f(x)-f(a_0)|<\varepsilon$

Comment: How about $f(x) = 1/x$ on $(0,1)$?

Comment: I see where $0$ is an accumulation point above and how that one creates problems for us but I am unsure of how to continue constructing our function.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Hint:** $A$ is not closed. So, there is a limit point of $A$ that is not contained in $A$. Use this point to construct a suitable function.

---

If $y \in \overline{A} \setminus A$, consider the function
$$
f(x) = \frac{1}{|x-y|}
$$

Comment: I still have not managed to get there. I saw that idea but I don't have any ideas on constructing an appropriate function.

Comment: See my latest edit

Comment: I understand. Thanks! I wasn't thinking about the fact that the accumulation point was not in the domain

Comment: Well... that's the whole point, if you think about it

Comment: If $y \notin A$ can we always define functions on A with reference to points not in $A$? Or is this only true when $y\in X \supset A$?

Comment: @akm You could define a function $f:A \to \Bbb R$ in whatever way you choose and with reference to anything you like as long as all operations within the function are valid. In this case, because $A \subseteq \Bbb R$, I can take advantage of the fact that $|x - y|$ is a valid operation (i.e. is "defined") for any $x \in A$ and $y \in \Bbb R$.